# How to transform an R Matrix into an xts/zoo object?

Tags: r, matrix, xts, zoo

aI'm having a problem transforming an xts derived R Matrix back into an xts object after running the returns function. Here's what I've got...

```
>    class(xtsData)
[1] "xts" "zoo"

> head(xtsData)
           ts_58_20_B_003_003 ts_58_20_S_021_005 ts_58_20_S_034_013 ts_58_20_S_042_021
2011-01-02            10001.0            10000.0              10000              10000
2011-01-03            10387.5            10001.0              10000              10000
2011-01-04            10387.5            10551.0              10000              10000
2011-01-05            10387.5            10562.5              10000              10000
2011-01-06            10387.5            10562.5              10000              10000
2011-01-07            10387.5            10562.5              10000              10000
> tail(xtsData)
           ts_58_20_B_003_003 ts_58_20_S_021_005 ts_58_20_S_034_013 ts_58_20_S_042_021
2013-03-05            21199.0              14905            10274.5               8859
2013-03-06            20498.0              14905            10274.5               8859
2013-03-07            20484.5              14905            10274.5               8859
2013-03-08            20957.5              15478            10847.5               9432
2013-03-11            20957.5              15478            10847.5               9432
2013-03-12            20531.5              14776            10847.5               9432
```

Following a procedure in the RMetrics documentation...

```
> xtsDataDiff <- xtsData[, ] / as.numeric( xtsData[1, ] )
> class( xtsDataDiff )
[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

When I apply the returns function I lose the returned object as an xts object...

```
> xtsData_1 <- returns( xtsDataDiff )
> class(xtsData_1)
[1] "matrix"
> tail ( xtsData_1 )
           ts_58_20_B_003_003 ts_58_20_S_021_005 ts_58_20_S_034_013 ts_58_20_S_042_021
2013-03-05       0.0000000000       -0.000099995        0.000099995        0.000000000
2013-03-06      -0.0337266853        0.000099995        0.000000000        0.000000000
2013-03-07      -0.0005588228        0.000000000        0.000000000       -0.000099995
2013-03-08       0.0228280749        0.037722934        0.054169546        0.062774267
2013-03-11       0.0000000000       -0.000099995        0.000099995        0.000000000
2013-03-12      -0.0206362804       -0.046315423        0.000000000        0.000000000
```

When I try to re-establish the data set as an xts object I get an error.

So my question is this... How do I re-establish the data of the matrix as an xts object?

Comment: How do you try to convert `xtsData_1` to an xts object?  What error do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is to convert your matrix again to an `xts` object. Using `as.xts` or `xts` constructor For example:

```
 xts(xtsData_1,as.POSIXct(rownames(xtsData_1)))
```